# How do I ask a potential employer about healtchare?

Tags: health, employment

I'm a new permanent resident of the United States living in California. I'm originally from a country that has universal healthcare where I didn't have to worry about health insurance because it was free. I needed it when I was unemployed.

Now that I'm living in the United States, I'm looking for a well-paying job in the IT industry and I have no idea what I should be asking a potential employer about healthcare. Health care seems insane in this country. Can any American from California give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It was in my country.

Comment: Did you pay taxes?

Comment: Not while I was unemployed.

Comment: It may be worth you looking at ExPats Stack Exchange - this seems like the sort of thing that is on topic there.

Comment: Wait til you get the offer and then ask to see the benefits package before accepting the offer.  Larger companies will have better plans and cheaper costs in general. I just moved from a billion dollar company to a medium sized one and my health care benefits for a worse plan went up from $35 a month to $135 every two weeks (family plans are much more expensive, so be prepared!). Make sure to consider these costs in determining salary. A smaller company may have to offer more in salary to make up for poorer benefits. And yes health care is insane in this country.

Answer (score 3):

Most employers will have at least an overview of their benefits on the 'careers' section of their website (if they have one).  Additionally, they'll almost always have a discussion of benefits (including healthcare) either with an actual HR person, or with the hiring manager.  If they do, feel free to ask for more information about how the healthcare works if you don't understand the benefit.

This is likewise a great topic when they do the normal "do you have any questions for me?" bit at the end.  "Hey, I'm new to the US and so I'm curious how your healthcare works in this company." is perfectly fine.

I would suggest that before you go in, you do some of your own research so that you understand the basics like HMO, PPO, etc.  Generally, most plans will involve some portion of your paycheck (before taxes) going to healthcare, and some portion of said fee also paid by the company.  Typically the things that vary are things like how much co-pay you owe on a visit (i.e. out of pocket; it's normally a flat fee like $20 or $30), if there is a deductible (and how much it is if so), caps on various services per year, and so on.  So a little research in advance to be able to ask intelligent questions.  Also, you normally can change your options each year, so decisions are not irrevocable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I pose a question like "How much will my premium and co-pay be?" in the interview? Who would I ask? Would it be the person who is hiring me?

Comment: The easiest way to do that is if there's an HR person that's part of the interview process. That's common in most larger companies; smaller ones ymmv.  If you get one, just ask them exactly that, or say, "Can I see the healthcare benefits options with costs?".  If you don't get an HR interviewer, then the hiring manager would be the next best bet, and same question.

Comment: @ArnaldoMontoya, Ask the HR person, that's their job to know this stuff. The hiring manager may know about his own premiums and co-pay, but if he has a family and you don't or if he chose a different plan, the amounts may not be the same, so chances are, he'll probably just tell you to contact the HR person anyway. Also, go on sites like glassdoor, employee reviews often talk about the level of benefits, if it's good or bad.

Comment: Do the costs vary from person to person or do they tend to be standard? Everyone pays $x ? Would they give a folder with all of this information in it in the interview?

Comment: Like I said there are usually a handful of plans available.  Often there's 2-3 plans, each with an "individual" and a "family" cost. Within those groups they're standard. $x/ month, etc.  As for having a folder ready, that varies from company to company.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question. What is usually the percentage premium an employer would pay? Half?

Comment: @ArnaldoMontoya, I actually don't know. Self-employment insurance varies by age. I can tell you that for sure. But when I was employed, that didn't seem to be the case (at least not that I can remember). No, not during the interview. Usually, it's better if you don't try to negotiate until they've decided to hire you. Also, you can ask for that info after they made you an offer, but usually such a folder is only presented to you on your first day of work. Usually, we go by the info that's presented on the web site, by the reviews on glassdoor, and the names of the insurance companies.

Comment: And yes, it's usually 1/2, but if they tell you your premiums are $300 a month (that's the actual amount you'll have to pay, the amount the company will pay has already been deducted).

Comment: @ArnoldoMontoya each company makes that decision for themselves.  They normally just tell you how much you'll pay; their cut is normally based on available budget.

Comment: Also, don't forget to ask for medical and **dental** coverage. Dental may not be covered unless it's explicitly mentioned and that can be very expensive too. Also, you may want to use your country of origin as your backup. I am French and I am insured in the US, but I still get regular checkups and expensive procedures done when I visit France (even if I pay the foreigner rate when I'm back there). The savings can pay for my trip.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Are health care premiums things that are usually negotiated before a job in the United States?

Comment: @ArnaldoMontoya, No, not at all. May be, you can try to get them started earlier than usual. Usually, they start after your probation period is over, but if you're already employed, you could argue that paying the COBRA rate from your previous employer all by yourself would be a downgrade in your benefits. COBRA is the interim payments you have to pay while you're unemployed to extend your previous insurance. It's usually more expensive because your former employer is no longer subsidizing it for you.

Comment: That being said, if a company wants to hire you through a third party contracting/consulting company or a temp agency, or if a company wants you to remain self-employed, or if a company wants you to work only part time (and not full-time), that usually means they don't want to pay/subsidize any benefit for you. So watch out for any job posting that suddenly becomes a contract position, when it was originally advertised as a full-time position.